# Cancel Service Call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I am using a WCF service, it is not an asynchronous service.
I do database operations in them. the Database operations return me huge result.
I want to provide a way to cancel the operation to my client.
Can anyone please suggest to achieve the same. I googled a lot 
also could find out some soluions, some are saying to make the service operation as asynchronous.This is what I got from msdn
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731177(v=vs.110).aspx
But how do I stop it.
Also as I am new to this, I am not able to figure out the thing.
Can anyone please help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your service synchronous but make async calls inside of your methods, around database queries for example. In this case you can use class [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which supports CancellationToken. But you should be on .NET 4 and up.

Comment: WCF tasks do not support cancellation.

Answer (score 0):

I you only want to cancel Service call (There is no session Locking (Session Creation/updation/deletion), you can make ajax call to service in `javascript` like :

```
   var xhr;

   var serviceUrl = "Service1.svc/GetData";
   xhr= $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: serviceUrl,
        data: "{\"value\":\"request\"}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            //anything you need to do on success
        }
    });
```

For aborting request, you can do :

```
  if(xhr && xhr.readystate != 4){
        xhr.abort();
    }
```

Please not that will abort the handler waiting for request & not request itself and  if you are playing with Session(except for read), it will not work & wait for request to complete.

If you have above case, its better to use [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as mentioned by vzayko.

Also if you're using MVC 4, you can also use [TAP(Task-based Asynchronous Pattern)](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4), which is specifically optimised for using tasks in ASP.net MVC.

Comment: I went through the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731177(v=vs.110).aspx. But I am not able to implement the cancel.Can anyone please tell me how to do that???

Comment: Its asynchronous call.Is it not possible to achieve the Cancel feature through this

Comment: Yes, that's seems to be Service implementation of Simple CallBack-Pattern. Use Can Use `Task` or  `Task-based Asynchronous Pattern` from links above

Comment: Is it not possible to have only one method as asynchronous, as I dont want to change my rest of code.

Comment: Is it that the Task is supported only in .Net 4.5

Comment: Task are in .net 4.0 but TAP is introduced in .net 4.5 only